# Is there a limit for how much ways are there to transform energy?

Tags: energy

Suppose a mechanical system that contains a single particle that is at a human scale height above the ground. There are numerous ways to transform the energy contained in the system. One is to transform $20$% of it into kinetic energy, leaving $80$% for gravitational potential. Another one is to transform all of it into kinetic, leaving no room for gravitational potential. This creates a way to partition the $100$% of the energy, but, are there infinite ways to partition it? Can it be changed in infinite ways, no matter how much of it there is?

Comment: I would start at Plank Constant and Boltzmann Constant. Energy is quantized, so you need Plank's constant for that. I reckon that limited number of packets would mean a limited number of possible organizations and change.  I am hoping someone would answer this. An interesting question that I would love to know the answer of.

Comment: Also, I think second law of thermodynamics would apply as well. Now, I really need an answer to this question.